# Word break not working even though max-width showing <p> smaller than max

Tags: html, css, sass

I am trying to do the simplist thing on my app but I can't quite get it to work. All I want is for the word 'Assessment'. To be on the next line down.

[image]

I have used the following css to create the div around it and the text itself.

```
#name{
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #353A50;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 12px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 12px;
  padding: 16px;

  p{
    font-family: Gibson SemiBold;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: white;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 16px;
    max-width:30px;
    word-wrap:break-word;
  }
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class="template-option">
  <div id="image"></div>
  <div id="name">
    <p>{{template.title}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Anything stupid I am doing?

Expected result:

```
Fire Risk
Assessment
```

Comment: Because 'Risk Assessment' isn't one word. In an ideal scenario when `word-wrap: bread-word` is used, 'Assessment' should have been broken into the other line and not as a whole word. I think the property you're looking for is `white-space` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

Comment: Spot on, required `white-space:normal;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All that was required is the following:

`white-space: normal;`

Answer (score -1):

Define a width for your p and give it display block:

```
#name{
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #353A50;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 12px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 12px;
    padding: 16px;
    width: 200px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    p {
        display: block;
        width:60px;
        font-family: Gibson SemiBold;
        font-size: 14px;
        color: white;
        margin: 0;
        line-height: 16px;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a nested `p` selector within `#name`. It should be its own rule, right?